# Characteristic polynomial of a classical arrangement of hyperplanes.

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-topology, root-systems

Consider in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ with standard basis $e_1, \dots , e_{n+1}$ the following hyperplanes arrangement $$ \mathcal{H}=\{H_i | H_i=e_i^\perp \}$$

Now let consider the restiction $\mathcal{H}^0$ of this arrengement to the hyperplane $H^0=\{(x_1, \dots , x_{n+1}) | \sum x_i = 0\}$ (i.e. the hyperplanes of $\mathcal{H}^0$ are the set of the intersections $H_i \cap H^0 \subset H^0 \simeq \mathbb{R}^n$)

Which is the Characteristic polynomial of $\mathcal{H}^0$?

Comment: You need a linear operator to be able to speak of a "characteristic polyomial".

Comment: @JeanMarie  For hyperplane arrangements, the term *characteristic polynomial* is defined differently.  See Section 1.3 (page 9) of http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis610/sp06stanley.pdf.

Comment: @Batominovski Thanks. The OP should have indicated it.

Comment: @JeanMarie  While that information is useful, my opinion (possibly not shared by others) is that it is unnecessary.  The OP has given sufficient indications (the combinatorics tag and the mentioning of hyperplane arrangements) for those who understand what hyperplane arrangements are---which is a prerequisite for this question---to know what the OP wants.  But certainly, more information does not hurt.

Comment: @SabinoDiTrani  I have one comment regarding the use of the word *canonical* here.  Some people may find it problematic to state that a vector space (even if it is equipped with an inner product) has a basis which is canonical.  There is nothing special about this choice of basis.  To my knowledge, the term *standard basis* is used instead (but that may be local).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Remark:  I use the index set $\{0,1,2,\ldots,n\}$ instead of $\{1,2,\ldots,n+1\}$.**

Let $[n]:=\{0,1,2,\ldots,n\}$.  For $I\subseteq [n]$, define
$$\pi_I:=\text{span}_\mathbb{R}\big\{e_j\,|\,j\in[n]\setminus I\big\}=\bigcap_{i\in I}\,H_i\text{ and }\pi_I^0:=\pi_I\cap H^0\,.$$
Then, the intersection poset $P:=L\left(\mathcal{H}^0\right)$ contains all $\pi_I^0$ with $|I|<n$.  Elements of a given rank $r$ of $P$ are of the form $\pi_I^0$ with $|I|=r$.  Furthermore, the partial order $\preceq$ on $P$ is given by setting $\pi_I^0 \preceq \pi_J^0$ if and only if $I\subseteq J$ or $|J|=n$.  Write $\pi^0$ for the point $(0,0,\ldots,0)=\pi^0_{I}$ for any $I\subseteq [n]$ with $|I|\geq n$.

Let $\mu:P\times P\to \mathbb{Z}$ be the Möbius function of the poset $P$.  Observe that, for a given $I\subseteq [n]$ with $|I|<n$, we must have $$\mu\left(\pi_J^0,\pi_I^0\right)=(-1)^{|I|-|J|}$$ for all $J\subseteq I$.  Furthermore, $\mu\left(\pi^0,\pi^0\right)=1$ and, for $I\subseteq [n]$ such that $|I|<n$,
$$\mu\left(\pi_I^0,\pi^0\right)=-\sum_{s=0}^{n-1-|I|}\,(-1)^s\,\binom{n+1-|I|}{s}=(-1)^{n-|I|}\big(n-|I|\big)\,.\tag{*}$$
Thus, the characteristic polynomial of $\mathcal{H}^0$ is given by
$$\chi_{\mathcal{H}^0}(t)=\sum_{v\in P}\,\mu\left(\pi_\emptyset^0,v\right)\,t^{\dim_\mathbb{R}(v)}=(-1)^n\,n+\sum_{d=1}^{n}\,(-1)^{n-d}\,\binom{n+1}{d+1}\,t^d\,.$$
That is,
$$\chi_{\mathcal{H}^0}(t)=\frac{(t-1)^{n+1}-(-1)^n(t-1)}{t}\,.$$

> **Here is a proof of (*).**  The number of elements $v\in P$ such that $\pi_I^0\preceq v \prec\pi^0$ such that the rank of $v$ is $s+|I|$ is $\binom{n+1-|I|}{s}$ with $$\mu\left(\pi_I^0,v\right)=(-1)^s\,,$$ and note that $s$ runs from $0$ to $n-1-|I|$.  Because $\sum\limits_{v\in\left[\pi_I^0,\pi^0\right]}\,\mu\left(\pi_I^0,v\right)=0$, we have $$\mu\left(\pi_I^0,\pi^0\right)+\sum_{s=0}^{n-1-|I|}\,(-1)^s\,\binom{n-1-|I|}{s}=0\,.$$

Comment: Thank you Batominovski!!! Just another question: can you explain better why you have the second equality in the following? $$\mu\left(\pi_I^0,\pi^0\right)=-\sum_{s=0}^{n-1-|I|}\,(-1)^s\,\binom{n+1-|I|}{s}=(-1)^{n-|I|}\big(n-|I|\big)\,.$$

Comment: @SabinoDiTrani  See the hidden box.